# Set Spanish Layout to an external keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I am using my Macbook Pro with an external display, and a external mouse and keyboard.  This is a Microsoft wireless keyboard 800 with Spanish layout. Is it possible to reconfigure the keyboard to set a spanish layout? because, the OS autoconfigure to English layout (same as on Macbook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, to make the OS match your keyboard, you go to **System Preferences / Language & Text / Input Sources** and check the box for what you want, in your case you should try *Spanish ISO* or perhaps *Spanish*.

Checking *Show Input Menu in Menu Bar* will display a *Flag* menu at the top right of the screen, under which you'll be able to select between your preferred keyboard layouts.

If neither *Spanish ISO* nor *Spanish* match your hardware, you can make a custom layout using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele)

Whatever layout you choose, it applies to both internal and external keyboards.